# IE Dropdown Nav menu hiding behind Slider

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm using a purchased template and having trouble solving an issue with my given code. Only in Internet Explorer, my dropdown nav bars fall behind the slide shows on my home page, and behind some img elements on other pages. I've tried other suggestions such as making my nav, `u`l,and `li`'s `z-index:10000`, and my sliders `z-index:-1`. Also tried some `z-index` variable script that was ineffective. Also there was some suggestion on another thread that mentioned making sure both nav and slider were position relative, they already were...
THIS ISSUE IS HAUNTING ME AND PREVENTING ME FROM FINISHING THIS SITE! THIS IS THE ONLY BUG LEFT.

My Url is www.premieravc.com.

I know there are hundreds of threads out there on this issue but with the specific template I have purchased, I still haven't found the solution.  The template is Quickr HTML Responsive from 4grafx and I have yet to receive a response from the developers.

Please help,
TJP

Comment: Maybe you should post some relevant code?

Comment: I'm new to coding and first time poster. The CSS code is so thick that if I were to post all of the CSS relevant to the nav menu and the slider menu it may be extremely long. Is that something that is normal here at Stack Overflow. And can't you see my css and html by viewing the page source?

Answer (score 0):

I has something to do with the CSS styling your using for the nav, it works fine in IE9, I see you've got some webkit padding, Try taking it away.

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1.67em;  
-webkit-margin-after: 1.67em;  
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;  
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
```

Also very nice site :)

Comment: Thanks for the compliments, and this is the last issue I need to resolve before we start to advertising. Which makes it even more disappointing. I tried taking out the ie webkit padding but that still did nothing. I've fiddled with z-index in my nav css and even my sf-menu and nav li css.